# Action is not Invoked when Submit button clicked in MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

As title says, my beginform is not firing, can someone see what i am missing?

```
 <div class="row">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "BlogPosts", new { blogid = blogidx }, FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Author)
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(o=>o.Comment)
            <button type="submit">Post comment</button>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's not "firing"? It's not mean to "fire".

Comment: I want it to execute the method "AddComment", is this not the correct way?

Comment: You want to execute it _when_? And that's not a "method", strictly speaking. It's an _Action_ on the "BlogPosts" _Controller_.

Comment: Allright, I want it to execute when i hit the submitbutton. Thank you

Comment: Ok, and what _does_ happen when you click the Submit button?

Comment: Nothing as far as I can tell. I have a breakpoint in the "AddComment"-action but it does not get hit.

Comment: What URL appears in the browser after you click "Submit"? What HTTP request is made when you click "Submit"?

Comment: what do you mean by `new { blogid = blogidx }`? I think it should be `new { id = blogidx }`, there is no `blogid` html attribute

Comment: @SergeyBoiko that part is correct actually, just the way I have namned the vars. But John is onto something. When I hover over the submit-button, nothing shows up in the bottom left corner of ther browser.

Comment: @user2915962, sorry, you are right

Comment: @user2915962 please, provide in your question code of the action `AddComment` and default routes

Comment: Thank you @SergeyBoiko but I just realised the problem. What does not show in my question is that I have got an Form-tag outside the div class="row">, when I deleted that, it worked. Dont know why but im sure if I had included it in may question someone might had known. Thanks!